# Xlib GLX not working ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, graphics

I upgraded to ubuntu 11.10 and now I cannot run Google Earth or other applications that require GLX. Here is what I got when i ran unity_support_test. How do I fix this?

```
aurora@eurus:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Segmentation fault
```

I am using a DELL Inspiron N5110

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
```

Comment: What graphics card does it have? Please add the output of `lspci -nn` to your question. Have you installed proprietary drivers directly from the vendor (i.e. AMD or nvidia?)

Comment: Updated the info. Ubuntu could not find any proprietary drivers.

Comment: Please attach /var/log/Xorg.0.log to your question. Paste it on http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/880767/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've installed the nvidia driver which breaks your graphics:

> [    37.912] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)

Uninstall the `nvidia-current` package and restart the X server (by rebooting for example). Your laptop is supposed to have a nVidia card (Optimus though). Your BIOS is configured to use the integrated card only. If you wish to have on-demand use of the graphics card (keeping the discrete nVidia card off at other times), have a look at Bumblebee as mentioned in [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969)